# How to deal with '#mysql50#.cache' database?

Tags: mysql, syntax, system-databases

I found '#mysql50#.cache' database on my `mysql`. Is this something standard? I can't select this database and look what is inside it because of it's name. Can I drop it?

Comment: Apparently it's related to upgrading MySQL. Found this blog: http://mattiasgeniar.be/2010/08/07/mysql-upgrade-to-5-1-database-name-prefix-mysql50/

Comment: You should be able to select it by quoting it with backticks.

Answer (score 1):

This is some folder (named `.cache`) in your database directory, that is not supposed to be there (and which is prepended by #mysql50#).

Barmar's suggestions didn't help me.

Instead I had to (re)move the folder to get rid of the message.

See:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/34388/53421

Answer (score 0):

I have been dealing with this problem on multiple servers.
I have 3 solutions...

1/Delete the offending directories!
  But they may return

2/ Tell MySQL Server to ignore them...
  That is modify "my.cnf" file in the "[mysqld]" section..

```
ignore-db-dir='lost+found'
ignore-db-dir='.cache'
ignore-db-dir='.config'
ignore-db-dir='.ssh'
```

And restart MySQL server...

3/ Modify the "automysqlbackup" which is generally the thing reporting problems with these 'databases' existing.

The problem is that simple attempts to add those database names to $DBEXCLUDE does not appear to work, and the scripts programming when processing "$DBNAMES" = "all" may need to be modified.

See...
   http://www.ict.griffith.edu.au/anthony/info/apps/mysql.txt